# Only authenticating some channels on join in Phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, phoenix-channels

How can I change this code to connect to a channel that doesn't require authentication, while still allowing authentication on some channels?

**phoenix.js:701 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:4000/socket/websocket?token=&vsn=1.0.0' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 403**

user_socket.ex

```
defmodule App.UserSocket do
  use Phoenix.Socket

  ## Channels
  channel "collection:*", App.CollectionChannel

  ## Transports
  transport :websocket, Phoenix.Transports.WebSocket
  # transport :longpoll, Phoenix.Transports.LongPoll

  # Socket params are passed from the client and can
  # be used to verify and authenticate a user. After
  # verification, you can put default assigns into
  # the socket that will be set for all channels, ie
  #
  #     {:ok, assign(socket, :user_id, verified_user_id)}
  #
  # To deny connection, return `:error`.
  #
  # See `Phoenix.Token` documentation for examples in
  # performing token verification on connect.
  @max_age 2 * 7 * 24 * 60 * 60
  def connect(%{"token" => token}, socket) do
    case Phoenix.Token.verify(socket, "user socket", token, max_age: @max_age) do
      {:ok, user_id} ->
        {:ok, assign(socket, :user_id, user_id)}
      {:error, _reason} ->
        :error
    end
  end

  def connect(_params, _socket), do: :error

  # Socket id's are topics that allow you to identify all sockets for a given user:
  #
  #     def id(socket), do: "users_socket:#{socket.assigns.user_id}"
  #
  # Would allow you to broadcast a "disconnect" event and terminate
  # all active sockets and channels for a given user:
  #
  #     Style.Endpoint.broadcast("users_socket:#{user.id}", "disconnect", %{})
  #
  # Returning `nil` makes this socket anonymous.
  def id(socket), do: "users_socket:#{socket.assigns.user_id}"
end
```

collection_channel.ex

```
defmodule App.CollectionChannel do
  use App.Web, :channel

  def join("collection:lobby", _params, socket) do
    {:ok, socket}
  end
end
```

app.js

```
import socket from "./socket"

let channel = socket.channel("collection:lobby", {});

channel.join()
  .receive("ok", resp => console.log("joined the collection channel", resp))
  .receive("error", reason => console.log("join failed", reason));
```

socket.js

```
import {Socket} from "phoenix"

let socket = new Socket("/socket", {params: {token: window.userToken}})
```

Comment: Is there any error output printed on the elixir side? And in your websocket-url, is there a token specified or is it empty?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To remove authentication, instead of verifying the token, always return a `{:ok, socket}` tuple inside the `connect` callback:

```
  def connect(_params, socket) do
    {:ok, socket}
  end
```

And make your `id` callback return `nil`, since all sockets are anonymous

```
def id(socket), do: nil
```

### Edit: Channel based authentication

If you want to have both, authenticated and anonymous channels, you will either have to handle authentication in the `join/3` callback of your channel, or specify via socket-assigns, if the user is allowed to join the channel.

For example:

```
  def connect(%{"token" => token}, socket) do
    case Phoenix.Token.verify(socket, "user socket", token, max_age: @max_age) do
      {:ok, user_id} ->
        {:ok, assign(socket, :user_id, user_id)}
      {:error, _reason} ->
        :error
    end
  end
  def connect(_params, socket), do: {:ok, socket}
```

This will allow anyone to join, but only sets the `user_id` when he is authenticated

```
# authenticated_channel.ex
defmodule App.AuthenticatedChannel  do
  use App.Web, :channel

  def join("authenticated:lobby", _params, socket) do
    if socket.assigns[:user_id] do
      {:ok, socket}
    else
      {:error, %{reason: "unauthorized"}}
  end

end

# unauthenticated_channel.ex
defmodule App.UnauthenticatedChannel do
  use App.Web, :channel

  def join("unauthenticated:lobby", _params, socket) do
    {:ok, socket}
  end
end
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this while still being able to authenticate some channels, but not others?